# Positive kernel property

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $k:[0,1]^2\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function and let
$f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ be measurable functions. We assume that
$$\forall x\in [0,1],\quad 
f(x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y) g(y) dy,\hskip15pt g(x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) dy.
$$
We want to prove that $f=g$.

Note that defining the operator $K$ by $(Ku)(x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y) u(y) dy$, this amounts to proving that the assumption $f=K^2f$ implies $f=Kf$ for a positive $f$. In other words, if 
$(Id-K^2)f=0$, it should imply $(Id-K)f=0$ whenever $f$ is positive. If the operator $Id+K$ were one-to-one, it would imply the sought result, but I do  not see why this invertibility property should hold.

Comment: Something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 5):

This is related to [Leray's Eigenvalue Problem](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ad48YMk8Hh0C&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=%22Leray%20Eigenvalue%20Problem%22&source=bl&ots=-X8WYLuojy&sig=Q_Bqhtq5_2yzVWSZBVS6aldV2Y8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=j6zrUtPFJuO10wXS_oGgBQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Leray%20Eigenvalue%20Problem%22&f=false) . Under your hypothesis, there is at least one positive eigenvalue, with a corresponding non negative eigenvector $u$ such that
$$
Ku = \lambda u,
$$
by Arzela-Ascoli's Theorem and Brouwer's Fixed point applied to
$$
F(u)(x)= \frac{\int_0^1 k(x,y) u(y) dy}{\int_0^1\int_0^1 k(t,y) u(y) dy dt}.
$$ 
Now, you have $K^2$ a positive, compact, linear operator acting on $L^{\ldots}(0,1)$ such that both
$$
K^2(f)=f \mbox{ and } K^2(u) = \lambda^2 u,
$$ 
that is, two stricly positive eigenvalues with positive eigenvectors. By the uniqueness property of such eigenpairs (Perron-Frobenius / Krein-Rutman Theorem)  $\lambda=1$, and $f=u$, so indeed, $Kf=f$.